# Creating migration through generator in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making an plugin in ROR and I want to make a migration file that will create a table. I am using generator for generating migration but not able to run it .

So please tell me the exact process to create a migration through generators.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://izumi.plan99.net/manuals/creating_plugins-938a313a.html

go to this url